# Pushing to array of webpack entry files

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. TypeScript is complaining that `server` does not exist in my webpack entry field.

To simplify the problem I trimmed it down to this:

```
interface Entry {
    [name: string]: string | string[];
}

interface WebpackConfig {
    entry: Entry
}

var config : WebpackConfig = {
    entry: {
        server: ['server'],
        client: ['client']
    }
}

config.entry.server.push('another');
```

Error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
webpack.config.ts (75,18): Property 'server' does not exist on type 'Entry'
```

Per my `Entry` interface, entry can have any property.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Entry%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7C%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20WebpackConfig%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20entry%3A%20Entry%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20config%20%3A%20WebpackConfig%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20entry%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20server%3A%20%5B%27server%27%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20client%3A%20%5B%27client%27%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconfig.entry.server.push(%27another%27)%3B)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Entry` interface is defined as an indexable type which means that you access the elements using the square brackets and not using dot.

This is how you should do it:

```
config.entry["server"].push('another')
```

That will also fail because you can not use `push` on the type `string | string[]`, but this will do it:

```
let item = config.entry["server"];
if (item instanceof Array) {
    item.push('another');
}
```

If you want to be able to access the items using the dot notation then you better do this:

```
interface Entry {
    server: string | string[];
    client: string | string[];
    [name: string]: string | string[];
}
```

And then you can:

```
let item = config.entry.server;
if (item instanceof Array) {
    item.push('another');
}
```